# OpenCV Haar Classifier XML Generation Error

Tags: c

I am going through with the Haar Classifier in OpenCV. I am going through with this link which is

http://note.sonots.com/SciSoftware/haartraining.html#n43ec47f

I am facing problem in ./mergevec executable, error is

```
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (elements_read == 1) in icvGetHaarTraininDataFromVecCallback, file cvhaartraining.cpp, line 1859
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'
  what():  cvhaartraining.cpp:1859: error: (-215) elements_read == 1 in function icvGetHaarTraininDataFromVecCallback
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on various sized instances and was not thrilled with recompiling each time so I ended up going with randomcastle's mergevec python replacement.   https://github.com/wulfebw/mergevec